# Ten targets you need to hit

Tags: probability

You are a good sniper and there are 10 targets you need to hit. The chance of hitting any target is the same.

Strangely, with your accuracy the chance of getting 8 hits is equal to getting 7 hits in 10 hits.

Then

> What is the exact chance of hitting all targets?

Note that the chance of getting hit is greater than $0$ and not $100$% either.

Comment: Just realised what the question was actually asking so edited my answer to include it :)

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't really satisfy the condition of "good sniper" ;)

Comment: @Kevin hahah you are right, it was misdirection :)

Comment: @Kevin : why not? The targets might be so far away and so small, that average snipers won't hit at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> $\left(\frac{8}{11}\right)^{10} \approx 0.0414$

If $p$ is the probability of hitting a target on any turn then the actual probability of hitting seven targets is

> $\binom{10}{7} p^7 (1-p)^3$

and the chance of hitting eight targets is

> $\binom{10}{8} p^8 (1-p)^2$

That means we want

> $\binom{10}{7}(1-p) = \binom{10}{8}p$ 
>  $\Rightarrow 120(1-p) = 45 p$ 
>  $\Rightarrow 165p = 120 \Rightarrow p = \frac{8}{11}$

and the probability of hitting $10$ is

> $p^{10} = \left(\frac{8}{11}\right)^{10} \approx 4.14\%$

Comment: I _knew_ I was missing something! Great answer

Comment: Okay this makes a lot more sense in my brain hole. And 8/11 is pretty darn close to my suggested 75% :P

Comment: Yeah @AHKieran, using your intuition is a good idea in this instance to get the ballpark figure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is allowed, but:

> Either 0% or 100%.

Comment: good catch, added a note :)

Answer (score 2):

If your accuracy is:

> 75%

Then

> Chances are, you'll get 7 or 8 hits, but the chances of it being either are equal.

So

> The chance of hitting all the targets is 0.75^10 = 0.0563135147 = ~5.6%

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the chance of hitting one target is p. The chance of hitting 7 or 8 are equal so:

> p^7 * (1-p)^3 * (10 * 9 * 8) = p^8 * (1-p)^2 * (10 *9)

Since 0 < p < 1, we can

> divide both sides by p^7*(1-p)^2*(10*9).
>
>  (1-p) * 8 = p
>
>  p = 1/9

So the chance of hitting all targets is

> (1/9)^10

Comment: Unfortunately you missed some terms in your combinations.  The way to choose three targets is (10*9*8)/(3*2*1) and choosing two targets is (10*9)/(2*1).  If you solve from there you'll get the same answer given by hexomino

Comment: Yeah, I tried to fix my original error and made it worse :P But hexomino already explained it better anyway so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> $\frac{1}{2^{10}} = \frac{1}{1024}$.

Let

> $p$ be the probability of hitting. By binomial distribution, if the chance of hitting 7 or 8 is identical, then $p^7(1-p)^3 = p^8(1-p)^2 \Rightarrow p = 1-p \Rightarrow 2p=1 \Rightarrow p=\frac{1}{2}$.

Then the probability of hitting 10 is

> $p^{10} = \frac{1}{2^{10}} = \frac{1}{1024}$.

Comment: Augh, beat me by a minute...!

Comment: i understand how you came to your conclusion but it doesn't sit right in my head. Does this imply that the chance of hitting any number of targets out of the 10 shots is equal?

Comment: @jafe close one!! Great minds think alike!

Comment: Hexomino has the actual right answer, for what it’s worth — I rushed without considering combinations